# Linux server supervision with manager not in local network

Tags: linux, snmp, system-monitoring

I have several Ubuntu 16.04 servers (the "hosts") on a local network and I want to monitor them with a CentOS 7 server (the "supervisor") which is not on the local network.

I want the transmision to be only " host -> server ", I am using SNMP Traps to alert the supervisor but when the traps are received they all have the same ip address and we can't know who is the sending host.

How can I can identify the sending host ? Or is there a different way to monitor them ?

Comment: What are you using for sending snmp traps ? more details are needed ?

Comment: I'm using Net-SNMP and the command snmptrapd